# How can I make all inserted images in the textarea 100% wide

Tags: asp.net, tinymce, tinymce-4

I've been testing Tinymce for the last couple of days and it's pretty cool. However I wonder if there is any possibility to change automatically the width of all images to 100% and height to auto whenever a user inserts an image inside the TEXTAREA.

The reason is that on my display page all images are 100% wide. This can be achieved by a simple css file but I couldn't figure out how to make those images 100% wide inside the form textarea.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        content_css : "/mycontent.css"    
});
```

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:content_css

So you can apply same styles of the final content on the editor content

Comment: @Micheal B I've tested it by creating a special css file for the Tinymce textarea to test its behavior. I managed to change the default font size but images didn't react to width:100% and height:auto. They didn't respond to the textarea size either.

Comment: did you inspect/firebug the image to see if it is actually picking up the style rule or there other rule overwriting it? will no to see code sample

Comment: That's exactly what I did and finally noticed that none of the images picked up the style because Tinymce was picking a cached version of the Style sheet. So I had to refresh the sulution. That never happened before. But your advice was the right one thanks.